# Google Maps API with backbone, how to bind an event

Tags: google-maps-api-3, backbone.js, underscore.js

I've seen several other posts about this, but the answers from those responses don't work for me.

The other responses:

[How do I bind a google maps geocoder.geocode() callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10516561/how-do-i-bind-a-google-maps-geocoder-geocode-callback-function)

[Backbone.js with Google Maps - problems with this and listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379303/backbone-js-with-google-maps-problems-with-this-and-listeners)

My code:

```
var ns = namespace('camelcase.geomanager.map');

ns.Site = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: '/site'
});

ns.Sites = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: ns.Site
});

ns.MapView = Backbone.View.extend({
    
    initialize: function() {
        this.markers = new Array();
        
        // Create the Google Map
        var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
                zoom: 8,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        this.googleMap = new google.maps.Map(this.$(".mapCanvas")[0], mapOptions);
        
        // Register events
        this.collection.on('add', this.addSite, this);
        this.collection.on('remove', this.removeSite, this);
    },
    
    addSite: function(model) {
    // Get model attributes
    var elementId = model.get('elementId');
    var latitude = model.get('latitude');
    var longitude = model.get('longitude');
    var id = model.get('id');
    var notes = model.get('notes');
    var title = ""+id;
    
    // Create icon and marker
    var icon = '/resources/img/elements/' + elementId + '_marker.png';
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        title: title,
        map: this.googleMap,
        icon: icon
    });
    
    // Load info window
    var siteBubbleTemplate = _.template($('#siteBubbleTemplate').html());
    var siteContent = $(siteBubbleTemplate({
        siteId: id,
        siteNotes: notes
    }))[0];
    
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: siteContent
    });
    
    // Show info window when clicking on marker
    _.bindAll(this, this.openSite);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', this.openSite(id));
        
        this.markers.push({
            id: id,
            marker: marker,
            infoWindow: infoWindow
        });
        
    },
    
    openSite: function(id) {
        var marker;
        for (var c=0; c<this.markers.length; c++) {
            marker = this.markers[c];
            
            // Open the appropriate marker info window
            if (marker.id == id) {
                marker.infoWindow.open(googleMap, marker.marker);
            }
            
            // Close the rest
            else {
                marker.infoWindow.close();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The offending line:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', this.openSite(id));
```

The error being reported in firebug:

> TypeError: func is undefined
>
> underscore.js (line 482)

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this.marker is the problem, since you should be able to just refer to it by name.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', this.openSite(id));
```

Comment: Good catch, but that didn't solve my problem.  I will update my post with the problem firebug is reporting.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it was a scoping issue.  I solved my problem with the following code:

```
// Show info window when clicking on marker
_.bindAll(this);
var _self = this;
var doSomething = function(event) {
    _self.openSite({
        event: event
    });
};
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', doSomething);
```

I'll give the answer to whoever can best explain why this works.

Answer (score -1):

In a model/collection event handler, Backbone sets 'this' to the model/collection which raised the event.  If you call _.bindAll(this) in your view's initialize(), 'this' will be set to the view in your event handlers.  Check out this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9cvVv/339/ and see what happens when you uncomment _.bindAll(this);

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        // TODO: uncomment this line
        // _.bindAll(this);
        this.collection.bind('myEvent', this.onDoSomething);
    },

    updateCollection: function() {
        this.collection.doSomething();
    },

    onDoSomething: function() {
        if (this.models && typeof this.models.length === 'number') {
            alert('"this" is a collection.');
        }
        else if (this.collection) {
            alert('"this" is the view.');
        }
        else {
            alert('"this" is something else.');
        }
    }
});
```